# Python pymongo not authorized for query

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am using [pymongo](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/installation.html) to connect with mongodb, but I unable to access the data.

```
import pymongo
client = pymongo.MongoClient()
db = client['db_name']
for i in db.<collection>.find():
        print(i)
```

Error.

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: database error: not authorized for query on <collection>
```

Comment: You'll probably need to authenticate with correct credentials then, however your database is set up.

Comment: @AKX how to do it in pymongo

Comment: Check out the [Authentication Examples](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/authentication.html#authentication-examples) in the docs